# Google Play Games: loadAchievements order does not reflect Play Store Console order

Tags: android, sorting, google-play-games

I am currently displaying my app achievements in a list with [loadAchievements method](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/GamesClient.html#loadAchievements%28com.google.android.gms.games.achievement.OnAchievementsLoadedListener,%20boolean%29)

The problem is that the items are returned in a random order and I would like to order them like they are ordered in the console. There is even an option to change their position, so I don't understand what this is for...

[image]

Any idea how to sort then?

Answer (score 0):

They are not really in random order, but if I remember correctly they are ordered by unlocking/completion status. What I mean is if if you have only unlocked achievements, or only locked achievements (0% incrementals), the order is correct.

Unfortunately, I don't think it's possible to change that order.

(That's the reason why I developped my own UI for this achievement list)